# Why it appears the error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS when user access the send certificate page?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code below that should redirect the user to the send certificate page.

But Im not understanding why, if the code is only like below (without validation) when the user click in the "Send certificate" link is redirected to the send certificate page "https://proj.test/conference/1/certificates/send", so it works correctly:

```
public function send($id, Request $request){

        $conference = Conference::with('registrationTypes.certificate')->find($id);

        $this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);
        return view('certificates.send')->with('conference', $conference);
    }
```

But if its like below (with validation), the user is redirected to the send certificate page but it appears a page with:

```
Page is not working
proj.test redirected to many times

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

Sometimes instead of appear the page with this errors the user is redirected to "https://proj.test/conference/1/certificates/create" instead of "https://proj.test/conference/1/certificates/send".

Same code with validation:

```
public function send($id, Request $request){

        $conference = Conference::with('registrationTypes.certificate')->find($id);

        $rules = [
            'send_to' => 'required',
            'subject' => 'required',
        ];

        $customMessages = [
            'send_to.required' => 'send_to is required.',
            'subject.required' => 'subject is required.'
        ];
        $this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);
        return view('certificates.send')->with('conference', $conference);
    }
```

Do you know what can be the error?

Routes:

```
Route::get('conference/{id}/certificates/create',
    [ 'uses' => 'CertificateController@create', 'as'=>'certificates.create']);

Route::get('conference/{id}/certificates/send',
    [ 'uses' => 'CertificateController@send', 'as'=>'certificates.send']);


Route::post('conference/{id}/certificates/update',
    [ 'uses' => 'CertificateController@update', 'as'=>'certificates.update']);
```

Answer (score 1):

the error message implies that you have a recursive loop.  does this send() function get called again while rendering the view perhaps?

Comment: Thanks, even if the content of the send.blade.php is just some text like "test" that error appears.

Answer (score 0):

I saw such an error message a few days ago. Not as a developer, but as a user. I needed to clear my cookies and then refresh the page that gave me this error.This solved the problem. I hope this gives you an idea on how to solve your issue.